# How to create a function in class that is not going to the prototyped function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When i create a function inside the class, TS compiler makes that function as prototyped function for example.

```
class MyClass {
    getExample()
    {

    }
}
```

the resultant is

```
var MyClass = (function() {
    function MyClass() {}
    MyClass.prototype.getExample = function() {};
    return MyClass;
})();​
```

but what i need is

```
function MyClass() {

    this.getExample = function() {

    }
}​
```

is it possible to get a function like this ?

Comment: I've never used TypeScript, but you could most definitely do the same, just put it in the constructor()

Comment: Might I ask why? The only difference is that, in the last case, the `getExample` method can be permanently deleted from your instances _and_ you'll create a new function object with each instance you create in your script... the prototype is there for good reason. The only application you might have is when you're using closure variables, but can't see any trace of those in your snippet

Comment: @Prinzhorn, consider i have more function, puttting whole thing in constructor() is not an efficitive way.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, yes i have some closure variables like `var that= this`.

Comment: @BalaKrishnan: Then it should suffice to assign a function to a variable, in the same way you're defining the closure vars. Just add `that.getExample = getExample;` at the end of your constructor, that _should_ do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-create-instance-methods-in-ts-rather-than-prototypes/) link, here is the answer for your question 'How to create a function in class that is not going to the prototyped function in TypeScript?', and there are more FAQs available.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at TypeScript (like the online playground... prefer writing my own JS, though :P)
As far as I can tell, what you want to do can be done quite easily, I've tried a few things myself and this worked like a charm for me:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    closureMethod;
    constructor (message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
        var that = this;
        var closureMethod = function()
        {
            console.log(that.greeting);
        };
        this.closureMethod = closureMethod;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}   
var greeter = new Greeter("world");
var another = new Greeter('Foobar');
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function()
{
    greeter.closureMethod();
    another.closureMethod();
}
document.body.appendChild(button)
```

Which worked, but even shorter (and this works, too)

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    closureMethod;//define property here, no type
    constructor (message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
        var that = this;
        this.closureMethod = function()
        {
            console.log(that.greeting);
        };
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

Both produce the same result: a constructor that defines a method over and over, for each new instance (which, honestly, is *not* a great idea).
As you can see, it accesses the instance using `that`, rather than `this`, which is the *only* upside of creating the same method over and over... as long as you have a good reason to do so. But I'm not going off in a rant on this.
The code above *works*, it generates a constructor function like the one you wanted.

Comment: If you use `this.closureMethod = () => console.log(that.greeting);` the `this` and `that` are managed for you by ts.

Comment: @SWeko: what do you mean? It's converted to regular JS, I've looked at the generated code, and using `that`makes a difference, consider this: `var foo = instance.closureMethod`, when I add `console.log(this === that);` to that method, `foo()` logs false: it's context is not the object that is referenced by `that`

Comment: sorry, I meant `this.closureMethod = () => console.log(this.greeting);`, and removing `that` entirely. The ts compiler automatically inserts a variable called `_this` that does the job of `that`

Comment: @SWeko: I've tried relying on `_this`, but TypeScript gives me an error: there is no closure var that references the instance being created. `that` is required in order for the function to work, even when the call-context changes Like in my previous comment, where I assigned a reference to the method to `foo`, and then called `foo()`. `this` would then point to the global object (`window`), and `window.greeting` is undefined --> not ideal, especially if I were to assign a value to a property: I'd be setting globals

Answer (score 1):

Methods you add to the constructor in TypeScript will be added as instance methods.

Methods you add outside the constructor and within the class will be added to the prototype of the object. This is the preferred way if you are "newing" up several instances of the class as it saves on memory. But when you do this you need to make sure you have access that you need to instances memebrs and the proper "this", which you can do by setting them in advance.

I recommend considering prototypes first, then falling back to instance if you truly need them for methods. If its a singleton object, then it really doesn't matter.

However ... when you create classes in TypeScript the concept of private and public does not translate to the emitted JavaScript. So keep this in mind as you are exposing every instance member in JavaScript. I prefer to use a pattern like the Module Pattern in JavaScript, which hides internal variables/methods and exposes only what I want to be accessible. You can get this with TypeScript by creating a function that returns the accessible members of an object (no classes). Just thought I'd mention the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static getSomething() {

    }
}
```

The static keyword means it is not a prototype method and you won't need to call it on an instance - just call it with:

```
MyClass.getSomething();
```

Of course, this may not be what you want - but you'll need to share why you need it to make that clearer.